# How to solve this simple yet troublesome differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=0$
I am a newbie to differential equations, and I tried to separate variables, but had no success. MY course only covered first order equations, but I am curious about how to solve this one. Thanks!

Comment: If you covered first order differential equations (systems included), then you can put $u=y'$ and $v=y$ and you get a first order linear system with constant coefficients.

Comment: I am sorry, I shouldn't have used the plural form of equations. I had nothing about systems.

Comment: Sometimes nothing is needed to go from single equations to systems.

Comment: Which system? Solve $v'-2v=0$ (no system), then solve $y'=v$ (no system either).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\frac{dy}{dx}=z$. Then $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dz}{dx}$. So our equation is:
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=2z$$
$$\int\frac{dz}{z}=\int2dx \implies \ln(z)=2x+c\implies z=z_0e^{2x}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=z_0e^{2x}$$
which is 1st order and can be easily solved.

Answer (score 1):

with  $$\frac{dy}{dx} = v, \frac{dv}{dx} = 2v \to v = 2ce^{2x}\to y =2c\int e^{2x}\, dx =c e^{2x} + b$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $y$ is of the form $e^{rx}$. Then the first and second derivatives are $re^{rx}$ and $r^2e^{rx}$. Plugging this into the equation gives, $$r^2e^{rx} - 2re^{rx} = 0,\text{ or, dividing by } e^{rx},$$
$$r^2-2r=0.$$
Should be easy enough to solve from here on.